# ionic 2 data showing some time, some time not

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have searched and done some API calling to show the data. But now when I run in browser or android device some time its showing, some times it's not showing, meaning that data is not already loading in the screen.

Here is my two screen full code include API calling:

My api calling code under my `src/provider/authservices.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


let apiUrl = 'http://www.example.com/api/';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}
 categ(cat: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(apiUrl+'categories.php', JSON.stringify(cat), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }

   allresources(allres: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(apiUrl+'AllResources.php', JSON.stringify(allres), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }

}
```

Next is my `schudle.ts`:

```
this.authService.categ(this.loginData).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.data = result;

       if(this.data.status == 1)
       {
       this.Catdata = this.data.CatgeoryList;


           for(let i=0; i<this.Catdata.length; i++) {
               //console.log(this.Catdata[i].CategoryName);
           }

       }

       else if(this.data.status == 0) {


       }

    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();

    }); 

opndetailpage() {
  console.log("button pressed");
  //this.navCtrl.push(SpeakerListPage, ResourcePage);

  this.navCtrl.push(SpeakerListPage).then(
      response => {
        console.log('Response ' + response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }
    ).catch(exception => {
      console.log('Exception ' + exception);
    });
}
```

my `html` :

```
 <div class="item item-body no-padding" style="border-width: 0px !important;">  

  <div class="row no-padding"  *ngFor="let data of Catdata;let i = index" (click)="opndetailpage()">
     <ng-container *ngIf=" i % 2 === 0">

          <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
               <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Catdata[i].CategoryName}}</span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
                 <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Catdata[i+1].CategoryName}}</span></div>
             </div>


     </ng-container>
</div> 


</div>
```

Then now my`detail page .ts`:

```
this.authService.allresources(this.resloginData).then((result) => {
   this.loading.dismiss();

      this.resdata = result;

       if(this.resdata.status == 1)
       {
       this.resCatdata = this.resdata.SubjectList;
           for(let i=0; i<this.resCatdata.length; i++) {
              // console.log(this.resCatdata[i].FileName);
           }



       }

       else if(this.resdata.status == 0) {

       }

    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
    console.log(err);

    });
```

That's it. Sometime if I navigate to detail page also, some time data are not showing. Am I calling the API wrongly or need to add some loaded data?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use Promise to wrap up the result rather than return Observable?

Comment: You can take a look at official example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

Comment: @SathishAL  Let me clear Your Issues. Initially, you can use ionic1 instead of ionic 2. it have all the features. But some times, this kind of navigation issue will have in ionic 2. Its better do it again from scratch to achive it.

Comment: @hybridDev No i tried more than 7 times, but i am getting the same issue. Due you have any source code or any body face this kind of issues

Comment: @SathishAL  Even i got this kind of navigation issue to populate the data. Not only for you... its the usual problem in ionic 2. still its not fixed. You can take a look of ionic 1 or you have to do it separate module wise like login,signup, side menu,tab..then integrate it both. But i am not sure again you will have this issue or not. So its better use ionic 1 and buy some plugin for that and achieve your target

Comment: @hybridDev  okay thanks. But If you find any solution let me know for this navigation issue. So that i can fixed it in ionic 2

Comment: @SathishAL   If you do it again also , i am not sure wether you will rectify it or not. Because ionic 2 have more navigation issue while we use side menu and tab. So go head with ionic 1 and add some plugin to achieve it. Once ionic 3 release out. You can use full pledged ionic 2 without any issues. Thats how it will work on..

Comment: @hybridDev   okay sure. But the navigation issues is working well with hard code value. But while doing the api call with navigation i am getting this issue. But api call i am doing correct only with the instruction gave in ionic documentations.

Comment: Yes, you are right !. the navigation issue will come once we call any api call from database. Dude go a head with ionic 1 and add some plugin. And make sure once ionic 3 release, you can solve this navigation issue. mostly many developers will prefer ionic 1 rather than ionic 2. If you get correct data from database .Its fine.Then your api calling method is correct. But sure you will get the navigation issues. ionic 1 always save ionic dev :-)

Comment: Okay, let me know if you got any.Thanks for your suggestions.